# docker: Error response from daemon: ttrpc: closed: unknown. after upgrading containerd to 1.4.0

Tags: docker, containerd

After upgrading containerd to 1.4.0, running docker containers fail with the following error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: ttrpc: closed: unknown.
```

For reference, I am using Arch Linux.

Comment: What's your question about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: As mentioned, A new version of containerd fixing this issue is available in arch repos: 1.4.0-2. (The broken version was 1.4.0-1). So below rollback is no longer needed.

---

Rolling back to containerd 1.3.4 fixes the issue for now:

```
cd /var/cache/pacman/pkg/
sudo pacman -U containerd-1.3.4-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
```

For a longer-term fix, there is already an open ticket on Github, it's probably best to track the status from there: https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/4483

Answer (score 0):

A new version of containerd fixing this issue is available in arch repos: `1.4.0-2`

> The broken version was `1.4.0-1`, and the fixed version is `1.4.0-2`